# In Rails, how can I create group of users as another association, such as "members"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to create a special relationship between two existing models, `User` and `Dwelling`. A `Dwelling` has only one owner (`Dwelling belongs_to :user`, `User has_one :dwelling`) at the time of creation. But other Users can be added to this `Dwelling` as `Roomies` (there is no model created for this now, `Roomie` is a conceptual relationship).

I don't think I need a separate model but rather a special relationship with the existing models, but I could be wrong. I think the reference needs to be made with `user_id` from the `Users` table. I'm not really sure where to start this. Thank you for any and all help!

For example:

```
Dwelling1 
  user_id: 1 
  roomies: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Where 1, 2, 3, 4 are user_ids.

**Updated Models**

`Dwelling Model`

```
# dwelling.rb
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :street_address, :city, :state, :zip, :nickname

    belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
    has_many :roomies, :class_name => "User"

    validates :street_address, presence: true
    validates :city, presence: true
    validates :state, presence: true
    validates :zip, presence: true

end
```

`User Model`

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  belongs_to :dwelling
  has_many :properties, :class_name => "Dwelling", :foreign_key => "owner_id"

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  ...
```

`Updated Dwelling Create Action`

```
#dwellings_controller.rb
...
def create
@dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])

  if @dwelling.save
    current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
    if current_user.save
      flash[:success] = "Woohoo! Your dwelling has been created. Welcome home!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @MurifoX, for cleaning up my question format!

Answer (score 2):

My answer assumes you only want a `user` to be a `roomie` at one `dwelling`.  If you want a `user` to be a `roomie` at more than one `dwelling`, I think @ari's answer is good, although I might opt for `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead of `has_many :through`.

Now for my answer:

I would set it up so that a dwelling `belongs_to` an owner and `has_many` roomies (including possibly the owner, but not necessarily).

You can use the `User` model both for `owners` and `roomies`.  You don't need any additional tables or models, you just need to setup the proper relationships by using the `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` options.

In your `Dwelling` model:

```
# dwelling.rb
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
has_many :roomies, :class_name => "User"
```

In your `User` model:

```
# user.rb
belongs_to :dwelling # This is where the user lives
has_many :properties, :class_name => "Dwelling", :foreign_key => "owner_id"  # This is the dwellings the user owns
```

In your `dwellings` table you need an `owner_id` column to store the `user_id` of the owner

In your `users` table you need a `dwelling_id` to store the `dwelling_id` of the dwelling where the user lives.

To answer your question in the comments regarding the controller:

If you want to setup `current_user` as the owner of the new dwelling, do this:

```
@dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])
....
```

If you want to setup the `current_user` as the owner AND a roomie of the new dwelling, do this:

```
@dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling]

if @dwelling.save
  current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
  if current_user.save
     # flash and redirect go here        
  else
     # It's not clear why this wouldn't save, but you'll to determine
     # What to do in such a case.
  end
else
   ...
end
```

The trickiest part of above is handling the case that the dwelling is valid and saves, but for some unrelated reason the `current_user` can't be saved.  Depending on your application, you may want the dwelling to save anyway, even if you can't assign the `current_user` as a roomie.  Or, you might want the dwelling not to be saved --- if so, you'd need to use a model transaction, which is bit beyond the scope of this question.

Your controller code didn't work because saving the Dwelling doesn't actually update the `current_user` record to store the `dwelling_id`.  Your code would be equivalent to the following:

```
@dwelling = Dwelling.new(params[:dwelling])
current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
if @dwelling.save
   ...
```

Note that `current_user` is never saved, so the `current_user.dwelling = @dwelling` line is useless.

This might seem counter-intuitive, but the bottom line is that `build_dwelling` isn't actually setting up things in memory as you might expect.  You'd achieve more intuitive results if you saved the model you're building *from* rather than the model you're building:

```
@dwelling = current_user.build_dwelling(params[:dwelling])
if current_user.save # This will save the dwelling (if it is valid)
```

However, this (by default) won't save the dwelling if it has validation errors unless you turn `:autosave` on for the association, which is also a bit beyond the scope of this question.  I really wouldn't recommend this approach.

Update:

Here is a more detailed code snippet:**

```
# dwellings_controller.rb

def create
  @dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])

  if @dwelling.save
    # The current user is now the owner, but we also want to try to assign
    # his as a roomie:
    current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
    if current_user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a dwelling"
    else
       # For some reason, current_user couldn't be assigned as a roomie at the 
       # dwelling.  This could be for several reasons such as validations on the
       # user model that prevent the current_user from being saved.
       flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a dwelling, but we could not assign you to it as a roomie"
    end
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    # Dwelling could not be saved, so re-display the creation form:
    render :new
  end
end
```

When a dwelling saves successfully, the current user will be the owner (`owner_id` in the database).  However, if the `current_user` doesn't save, you'll need to decide how your application should respond to that.  In the example above, I allow the dwelling to be saved (i.e. I don't rollback its creation), but I inform the user that he couldn't be assigned as a roomie.   When this happens, it's most likely other code in your application causing the problem.  You could examine the errors of `current_user` to see why.  Or, you could use `current_user.save!` instead of `current_user.save` temporarily to troubleshoot.

Another way to do all of this is with an `after_create` callback in the `Dwelling` model.  In many ways that would be a cleaner and simpler way to do it.  However, catching the case when the `current_user` can't be saved could be even uglier than the method above, depending on how you want to handle it.

I believe the bottom line is that the `current_user.save` code is causing some problems. You'll need to diagnose why, and then determine what your application should do in that case.  There are several ways to handle this, including at least the following

1. Put everything in a transaction block, and use `current_use.save!` instead of `current_user.save` so that an exception is raised and neither the user or dwelling is saved.
2. Save the dwelling, but inform the user that he isn't a roomie (As above)
3. Instead of saving the current_user, use `update_column` (which avoids callbacks, validations, etc.).

I believe the current problems you're experiencing are essentially unrelated to the original question.  If you need further assistance, it might be best to break it off as a separate question.

Comment: I have updated my question above to reflect the updates to the `User` and `Dwelling` models. I also added a `dwelling_id` column to `users` and an `owner_id` column to `dwellings`. Unless I am missing something else, it looks like the solution might be incomplete, though. I can successfully create a `Dwelling` through the web interface. However, after creation, none of the relationships exist. `user.dwelling` and `dwelling.owner` are `nil` and `dwelling.roomies` returns an empty array. Are both of the relationships supposed to be `belongs_to`? I've included my `create` action for `Dwellings`.

Comment: @justinraczak: The associations are correct.  When you use `build_dwelling` and `@dwelling.save`, it's like creating a new dwelling, and then assigning that dwelling to the `current_user` as his home.  It is his home in memory, but your controller never saves that fact to the database.  I'll update my answer with a better way to setup the controller action.

Comment: @Nathan I think I may not have implemented the solution correctly. I have updated my `Dwelling` create action above. But admittedly, I got a little confused with the various snippets in the revised answer, so I apologize if I didn't get it quite right. Right now, after a create, the page reloads on the `Dwelling` form but seems to be in the update state rather than create. When I query the `dwelling` in the console, the `dwelling` does have an `owner_id` but that `user` does not have the `dwelling_id`. Have I mixed up the solution?

Comment: @justinraczak: It sounds like the `Dwelling` is being saved, but the current_user is not being saved, so your controller is rendering the `new` view for the saved `Dwelling` object, which depending on how your view is coded, may just be effectively the same as the update form for the `Dwelling`.  If that's the case, you would want to figure how why the current_user isn't being saved.   In any case, if the user doesn't save, you probably don't want to render the `new` view for the `Dwelling`. I'll update my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: @Nathan: thanks for all your help with this so far. With your implementation, I can definitely see that the problem is in fact happening somewhere with saving the user, as the `else` branch of the create method is being triggered. I have opened a new question hopefully correctly expressing the problem here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812834/in-rails-how-can-i-automatically-update-a-user-to-own-a-newly-created-object-of[link]. Thanks again for all your help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible options. 
Depending on your plan, it might be clearer for the dwelling to have_one owner instead of the owner having one dwelling. Then the dwelling would also be able to have users. You can add a column to User called dwelling_id and then you could do dwelling has_many users.

Another option would be to use the ["has_many through" association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). This means you would need to create a new model that would keep track of this association, say "Relationship.rb", which would belong to both User and Dwelling (and have columns for both for them). Then you would be able to write code like this:

```
//in Dwelling.rb
has_many :roomies, through: :relationships, source: :user

//in User.rb
has_many :dwellings, through: :relationships
```

This would let users also join more than one dwelling.

Comment: Hi Ari, thanks so much for the suggestions. I think I am going to attempt to go the second route, creating the second table to house a relationship between the two via roomies. In this case, would the Roomie_Relationship.rb model be an empty model?

Comment: Also, do I need to add anything to my `User` model to enable this? I get the following error with the above implementation:

_ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :dwelling_roomie_relationships in model Dwelling_

I have added to my `Dwelling` model:

`belongs_to :user
has_many :roomies, through: :dwelling_roomie_relationships, source: :user`

And `dwelling_roomie_relationships.rb` is an empty model.

Comment: The relationship will need to have columns for each. You also need to add similar code to the User model, see my edit. Read my link to find out more about the topic.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer if you intend for a given `user` to be a `roomie` at more than one `dwelling`.  The answer I provided would only work if any given `user` was a `roomie` at only one dwelling.  Of course, a simple HABTM relationship with a simple join table would be simpler and more direct unless you need additional properties for the relationship.  Using `has_many :through` when `has_and_belongs_to_many` would suffice is controversial.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by storing Roomie ids as a column in Dwelling

Make a migration:

```
class AddRoomiesToDwelling < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :dwelling, :roomies, :text
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :dwelling, :roomies
  end
end
```

In your Dwelling model:

```
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :roomies
end
```

You can then set the roomie ids with:

```
roomie_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
@dwelling.roomies = {:ids => roomie_ids}
@dwelling.save!
```

Taken from the *Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns* section of [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799)

Comment: If you set it up this way, you have no easy way to determine which dwelling a particular roomie lives at. You would have to load all of the dwellings and unserialize the list of roomies for each one.

Comment: While this may be a viable approach, it just seems to disregard the value of having a relational database in the first place.  No offense @Sabar, I just honestly think this is a poor solution to the problem.

Comment: None taken, I just personally don't like creating another model for this kind of relationship

Comment: Hey @Nathan, that was exactly my concern with this approach. At a high level, this application manages a living situation for roommates - bills, shared expenses/purchases, property, etc. So the relationships between all of the entities/models needs to be explicit and rails-enabled.

 @Sabar, thanks a lot for the suggestion and it definitely makes sense if it was simply a matter of loosely tracking the relationships. But I need to enable things like `Dwelling.roomies` or `Roomie.dwelling`, etc.