# In Rails, how can I automatically update a User to own a newly created object of another class within the new object's Create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My application has `Users` and `Dwellings`. When a `user` creates a `dwelling`, the `user` becomes the `owner` of the `dwelling` through a rails association. Through my `create` method, the `user_id` is successfully assigned to the newly created `dwelling` in the `owner_id` column, however the `dwelling_id` is not propagated to the `dwelling_id` in the `user`'s record. I'm not sure if it is the relationship or method incorrectly set up, but the problem seems to occur when an attempt is made to save the `user`, as the `dwelling` is successfully created. Below are my models and method implementations.

**Dwelling Model**

```
# dwelling.rb
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street_address, :city, :state, :zip, :nickname

  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  has_many :roomies, :class_name => "User"

  validates :street_address, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :state, presence: true
  validates :zip, presence: true

end
```

--

**User Model**

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  belongs_to :dwelling
  has_many :properties, :class_name => "Dwelling", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
...
```

--

**Dwellings Controller (create method)**

```
# dwellings_controller.rb
def create
  @dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])

  if @dwelling.save
    current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
    if current_user.save
      flash[:success] = "Woohoo! Your dwelling has been created. Welcome home!"
    else
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a dwelling, but something prevented us from adding you as a roomie. Please email support so we can try to correct this for you."
    end
    redirect_to current_user
    else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

--

As mentioned above, the `dwelling` is successfully created but the "...but something prevented us from adding you as a rookie..." flash is triggered from the `else` conditional.

**Update 8/3/12 9:11PM EST**

I updated the `create` action to use `user.save!` to force the transaction. The following error was output. Apparently the password is required somehow.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in DwellingsController#create

Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank
```

Comment: Take a look at what is in current_user.errors after the failing save ... or make it crash to get the exception with `current_user.save!`

Comment: I agree with @Anthony. You should use `current_user.save!` instead of `current_user.save` in the controller.  This will raise an exception if the current user can't be saved, and then you'll know what the underlying problem is.

Comment: It may help to know that the seemingly redundant relationship between users and dwellings is intentional. See the original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779249/in-rails-how-can-i-create-group-of-users-as-another-association-such-as-membe

Comment: I have updated the question above to include the error output when using `user.save!` in the `create` action. Seemingly the requirement of a password somewhere in the process is causing the problem. Is this normal? If so, how can I provide it? If not, how can I remove this obstacle?

Comment: Not sure if I need to use the @Nathan to notify so just repeating here.

Comment: It should only check for the presence of password on `create` and not on `update`, according to the documentation for `secure_password`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L46 So strange that it's failing validation.

Comment: I posted an answer with some suggestions for troubleshooting.  You do have to add @Nathan if you're not commenting on my own question or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with saving the `user`. I updated my `create` action in the `Dwellings` controller to to force a save of the `user` using `user.save!` to break the application and get an explicit error. Rails complained of a missing `password` (and password length) and `password_confirmation`. I am enforcing a `presence` validation on both `password` and `password_confirmation` as well as a `length` validation on `password` in my `User` model. I updated these validations to be enforced only on `create`. This solved the issue. With the validations no longer being enforced on `user.save`, the `dwelling_id` was successfully added to the `user` record. The newly implemented code is below.

```
#dwellings_controller.rb
...
def create
  @dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])

  if @dwelling.save
    current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
    if current_user.save
      flash[:success] = "Woohoo! Your dwelling has been created. Welcome home!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a dwelling, but something prevented us from adding you as a roomie. Please email support so we can try to correct this for you."
    end
    redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
...
```

--

```
#user.rb
...
  validates :password, presence: { :on => :create }, length: { minimum: 6, :on => :create }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: { :on => :create }
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I misunderstood the user/dwelling relationship in the answer below, so this is not a solution to the problem.

---

I think you're misunderstanding how associations work. With a `belongs_to`/`has_many` relationship, only the model that *belongs to* (in this case, `Dwelling`) has a foreign key pointing to the other record (in this case, `User` through the foreign key `owner_id`). The other record (`User`) does not need a key for every association, which would be redundant.

Likewise, you don't need to assign `@dwelling` to `current_user.dwelling`, nor do you need to save the `current_user`. Just saving `@dwelling` after building it in `current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])` should be enough.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I didn't read your code carefully enough. Let me look over this again and update this answer.

Comment: I do understand the way it works, but with your suggestion the same scenario persists. The current implementation and your suggestion of edits produce the same results - a new `dwelling` with a `user_id` in the `owner_id` column of the new `dwelling` and no `dwelling_id` in the `user` record. A call to `user.dwelling` returns `nil`. So what is your suggestion for properly implementing the two-way relationship?

Comment: Ah perhaps ignore my response until then :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't grok the properties/dwellings distinction. Now I see what you're trying to do, and I don't immediately see why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem really depends on details of your application we haven't seen yet.  For example, we don't know what `current_user` is defined as, we don't know how your users are created, we don't know any details about your forms, etc.

I don't have much more time to work on this right now, but you might try the following things.

1. First, remove `has_secure_password` from your `User` model and see if you still experience the issue.  This is just for troubleshooting, as eventually you'll want to add `has_secure_password` back in.
2. Make sure your users table has a `password_digest` column.
3. Make sure the `current_user` has a value in the users table for `password_digest`  Perhaps you created the user before you added the `has_secure_password` feature, which would result in a NULL value for `password_digest`.
4. Make sure that `current_user` is actually a persisted (i.e. in the database) user.  You can do this by adding the following line above `current_user.save!`:

   ```
   raise StandardError, "current_user is not persisted" unless current_user.persisted?
   ```
5. I'm assuming `current_user` already exists as a persisted user.  If you're actually doing something fancier like trying to create the user and the dwelling in the same form, then there are several other factors that need to be considered.

I won't have additional time to help with this for a while.  Best wishes getting it solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Turns out the root of the problem was in my validations for my `User` model. I have `presence` validations for both `password` and `password_confirmation`. I updated those validations to be triggered only on `create`. This solved the original problem, but then the `user` was being signed out after creating a `dwelling`. This turned out to be the result of a `create_remember_token` call in a `before_save` filter for the `user`, which was changing the token and essentially destroying the session. This was fixed by updating the filter to `before_create`.