# In Rails, how can I pass a logged in user's password in a hidden field in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `dwelling` object that is built on a `user`.

**Dwellings Controller (create action)**

```
# dwellings_controller.rb
def create
  @dwelling = current_user.properties.build(params[:dwelling])

  if @dwelling.save
    current_user.dwelling = @dwelling
    if current_user.save!
      flash[:success] = "Woohoo! Your dwelling has been created. Welcome home!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a dwelling, but something prevented us from adding you as a roomie. Please email support so we can try to correct this for you."
    end
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The `dwelling_id` is not being saved to the `current_user` record. To get more information, I added the bang method (as shown above) to the `current_user.save!` command. Rails complains that the `user`'s password is required to update the record, as shown below.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in DwellingsController#create

Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank
```

If providing the user's password through a hidden field isn't the correct solution - and it does seem insecure - how can I correct this problem? Relevant sections of the `user` and `dwelling` model shown below.

```
#dwelling.rb
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street_address, :city, :state, :zip, :nickname

  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  has_many :roomies, :class_name => "User"

#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip, :dwelling_id
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  belongs_to :dwelling
  has_many :properties, :class_name => "Dwelling", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was stemming from my validations in the `User` model. The `presence` and `length` validations on `password` and `password_confirmation` were being imposed on `user.save`, which was failing as `password` and `password_confirmation` were not being provided. My update validations appear below.

**User Model**

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip, :dwelling_id
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token

  belongs_to :dwelling
  has_many :properties, :class_name => "Dwelling", :foreign_key => "owner_id"

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: { :on => :create }, length: { minimum: 6, :on => :create }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: { :on => :create }
```

With this updated implementation, the `user` is successfully saved and the appropriate attributes are updated. This is a secondary issue stemming from this original question: [In Rails, how can I automatically update a User to own a newly created object of another class within the new object's Create method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812834/in-rails-how-can-i-automatically-update-a-user-to-own-a-newly-created-object-of)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the password anywhere in the form, simply because the user's password is saved in the database (via has_secure_password) in an encrypted password digest format which cannot be decrypted. (The password is saved with one way encryption.) So there is no way to get the password out to put in anywhere in a form's hidden field (which would be a bad idea anyway).

Inspect your current_user in the log (logger.debug current_user) to see if current_user has a valid user (with a password) assigned to it.

Comment: It does. Turns out what I needed to do was enforce my validations (presence and length) for `password` and `password_confirmation` on `create` only.